# Exception inheritance

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance

Is it possible to have multiple elements in an exception class in c++, which I can associate with the exception, so that when I throw it, the user can gather more information about the exception than just an error message? I have the below class

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class myex : public out_of_range {
private:
    list<int> *li; 
    const char* str = "";
public:
    //myex(const char* err): out_of_range(err) {}
    myex(li<int> *l,const char* s) : li(l),str(s) {}

    const char* what(){ 
        return str;
    }       
};
```

When I throw a myex using

```
throw myexception<int>(0,cont,"Invalid dereferencing: The iterator index is out of range.");,
```

I get an error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::out_of_range::out_of_range()’.
Any help is appreciated.`.
```

When I uncomment the commented line, and remove the other constructor, then it works fine.

Comment: Saving a `const char*` here is *extremely* dangerous, as the string used to construct the exception is highly likely to go out of scope between the throw and the catch of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of your user-defined exception tries to call the default constructor of the class out_of_range... [Except it doesn't exist](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/?kw=out_of_range) !

About the commented constructor :

```
myex(const char* err): out_of_range(err) {}
                     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this calls the constructor of 
                     // out_of_range with the parameter err.
```

In order to fix your current constructor, you should add an explicit call to out_of_range's constructor (which takes a const string&):

```
myex(li<int> *l,const char* s) : out_of_range(s), li(l),str(s) {}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now, it was stupid of me to miss the out_of_range() constructor after inheriting from it.